# What really happens when jQuery is passed itself?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So I have a conundrum, and hope someone is already in possession of the answer. Reading jQuery source, I have yet to understand what really goes on here.

```
 $('#div')      //returns a jQuery object
 $( $('#div') ) // returns an identical jQuery object
 $( $( $( $( $( $('#div') ) ) ) ) ) // returns the same idential object
```

I have run into instances in plugin development where I don't know to expect a sting selector or a jQuery object. In those instances I had been simply passing the selector or jQuery object into jQuery so that I am guaranteed the jQuery object I want. It works well, but it feels too magical. What is really going on when I do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: There is no magic... that is by design.  You have many ways to specify a selector.  Strings, and DOM objects are all fine.

Comment: This is happening: http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.fn.init :)

Comment: @Brad I know that, and make use of that feature presently. I just want to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic I think in the function `$(...)` this exist some base case as.

- In Arg is of type String, Pass this and find or create the HTML Dom element then capsules this into JQuery object.
- In Arg is of HTML Dom type, capsules the object into a JQuery object
- In Arg is of JQuery Object, Return it as this is

But in real more case exist and a loot of debug and error check before this.

See more at http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.fn.init
What I can see from the code, If we has.

```
var x = $('#div');
var y = $(x);
```

content of `x` and `y` is equal
but memory of `x` and `y` is not equal.

Say we has:

```
class $ {
  var x;
  $($ t) {
    this.x = t.x
  }
}
```

This will do if we all call `$` this will has same intrinsic value
but not is not same in real as two different object.

Comment: which lines on fn.init handle this instance?

Comment: What I Can see, on line 177 to 182, not true sure on witch.
But I think what happen is, the jquery copy the element to the new.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering this question, one needs to understand, that $(...) returns a special object with array-like properties. From the documentation:

> jQuery factory function $() returns a jQuery object that has many of
>   the properties of an array (a length, the [] array access operator,
>   etc.), but is not exactly the same as an array and lacks some of an
>   array's built-in methods (such as .pop() and .reverse()).

So, this is what happens.

1. Regardless of the type of the selector, `new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );` is called, therefore a new object is created and its properties are set in this `init()` constructor.
2. Argument of $(...) undergoes checks for emptiness, DOMElement, string or function (via isFunction)

All the checks fail, and in the end the following code is called.

```
if (selector.selector !== undefined ) {
    this.selector = selector.selector;
    this.context = selector.context;
}
return jQuery.makeArray( selector, this );
```

Function makeArray() turns provided selector into an array-like object, by simply setting `this.length` property and `this.ret[0]=..., this.ret[1]=...` so that it "feels" like an array while it remains an object based on jQuery prototype (aka `$.fn`). Remember, that `this` in the code above is just a brand new object with `$.fn` in the prototype.
Additionally, `.selector` and `.context` properties are copied from the original to this.

It is important to note, that, e.g. `.prevObject` property will be lost, but a new one might be added depending on the method chaining.

All in all, it takes time and memory and it probably makes sense to simply check for `.selector` when someone might pass a jQuery object into your plugin. On the other side, new instance with the same behaviour as original might be helpful.